# confusion with weather command, how do i fix it?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am making a `,weather` command, and i want it to work for celsius, and fahrenheit which works but i want my command to detect the last argument, example `,weather toronto` would give me the weather in toronto in celsius, when i do `,weather toronto f` it gives me the weather in fahrenhiet, but when i do something like ,weather new york city f``` it does not give me the weather in fahrenheit, here is the code for that part, weather part is done by the weather-js npm

```
        if(args[1] == "C" || args[1] == "c"){
            var Degree = "Celsius"
            var Deg = "C"
        }
        else if(args[1] == "F" || args[1] == "f"){
            var Degree = "Fahrenheit"
            var Deg = "F"
        }
        else{
            var Degree = "Celsius"
            var Deg = "C"
        }
```

Comment: in `,weather new york city f`, "new york city" has spaces so it's treated like multiple arguments. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499406/get-command-argument-including-spaces/51499796

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` is an array of arguments given to the command, split by a spacing in most command handlers. Instead of having it not so user-friendly as suggested by other coders using a certain character to be split between the city name's words, if you are strict about the selection being at the last index you can access it using: `array[array.length - 1]`.

```js
let degree;
let deg;
if (args[args.length - 1].toLowerCase() === 'f') {
  degree = 'Fahrenheit';
  deg = 'F';
} else { // Keep in mind, checking if the last index is 'c' is not necessary, as we'll set it to celsius anyways.
  degree = 'Celsius';
  deg = 'C';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [Arguments](http://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html), the reason `,weather new york city f` does not work is because your command line is **split by spaces** and has a format of `[cmd] [location] [degree type]`.

*This would make* `new` *the location, and* `york` *the degree type*. Which ofcourse would not be valid.

---

One way to account for location names with spaces is by *having the input be divided by dashes* `-` (`new-york-city` instead of `new york city`) and then re-format the string using [String#split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Array#join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
// message.content = ',weather new-york-city f`
// const args ...

console.log(args);
// ['new-york-city', 'f']

args[0] = args[0].split('-').join(' ');
// ['new-york-city'] => 'new york city'
```

**If you prefer to maintain the spaces in the location, you can use this**

```
// const args ...
const Location = args.slice(0, args.length - 1);

// Using Optional chaining (?.) Since a degree argument is optional (node v14+)
const Deg = args?.pop();
```

---

**Your finalized code would look like this**

```
const Location = args.slice(0, args.length - 1);
const Deg = args?.pop()?.toUpperCase();

let Degree = '';
if (Deg === 'C' || !Deg) {
   Degree = 'Celsius';
} else {
   Degree = 'Fahrenheit';
}
```

Better yet, handle it all with a [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
const Location = args.slice(0, args.length - 1);
const Deg = args?.pop()?.toUpperCase();
const Degree = Deg === 'C' || !Deg ? 'Celsius' : 'Fahrenheit';
```

Comment: How is the 2nd one efficient? You're basically saying that it would only work if the city is 3 words long, not less, not more.